# Redis connects inside of EB instance but wont connect with deployed sailsjs application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, sails.js

I have created a redis cache for my node webserver that uses ElasticBeanstalk. They both share the same security group and if I ssh into my eb instance and do:
`redis-cli -h <redis server endpoint>` it works. But when I do the same thing on my SailsJS application and then deploy it to my EB Instance it does not work:

`/myapp/config/redis.js`

```js
const redis = require('redis')
module.exports.RedisClient ={
  client: redis.createClient('<redis server endpoint>')
}
```

The redis server does not use a password

And if I log the output of this it with `sails.config.RedisClient.client.connected`

The output is `false`

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the issue, the problem was that I was not appending the host endpoint with the redis protocol: `redis://`, so it never connected.

Correct code would be:

```js
const redis = require('redis')
module.exports.RedisClient ={
  client: redis.createClient('reddis://<redis server endpoint>')
}
```